# macOS Catalina installation error

Tags: macos, catalina, install, error

I am using a 2019 MacBook Pro. I am moving from macOS 10.14.6 to macOS 10.15 Catalina.

I just finished downloading the macOS Catalina installer via Software Update System Preferences pane, but when I try to install it, I run into an error as follows:

[image]

I have also downloaded macOS Mojave security update. What can I do to resolve and install macOS Catalina?

Comment: How much of empty disk space do you have in Macintosh HD? Try checking using Disk Utility.

Comment: @NimeshNeema 300Gb

Comment: Take a look through this thread, you may find something that resolves the issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8552490

Comment: @NimeshNeema I've done them all but still the same

Answer (score 1):

There was a known issue with upgrading Macs with a T2 chip, such as yours, to macOS 10.15.6. Apple have yet to acknowledge the problem but have rolled out (about 3 hours ago) a new update to the software catalog that is reported to fix the problem.

Give it another try now.

Comment: [this checks out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398719/5472)